# Variables randomly change after being set once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to spawn a GameObject every time one gets deleted at randomly generated locations across my map.

I have the following code to spawn my food

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject food;

    private Vector3 maxSpawnLimit;
    private Vector3 minSpawnLimit;

    private Vector3 spawnLocation;
    private Quaternion spawnRotation;

    private GameObject ground;

    private void Start()
    {
        ground = GameObject.Find("Ground");

        maxSpawnLimit = ground.transform.lossyScale / 2 + new Vector3(-1, 1, -1);
        minSpawnLimit = -ground.transform.lossyScale / 2 + new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

        Debug.Log("Start Spawn limit " + maxSpawnLimit + minSpawnLimit);
    }

    public void SpawnFood()
    {
        spawnLocation = new Vector3(Random.Range(minSpawnLimit[0], maxSpawnLimit[0]), 0, Random.Range(minSpawnLimit[2], maxSpawnLimit[2])) + new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
        spawnRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        Instantiate(food, spawnLocation, spawnRotation);
        Debug.Log("Spawn Limits " + maxSpawnLimit + minSpawnLimit);
    }
}
```

I ran a `Debug.Log` on the max and min spawn limits when they are set in the start method and they do not change, although I did the same in the SpawnFood method and the limits change from `(49, 1, 49)` which they should be, to `(0, 0, 0)` after the first bit of food is spawned. Why is this?

EDIT:
The inspector for the object that the `SpawnManager` script is attached to https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJQMy.png

The script showing the collision detection and subsequent method calling and object deletion

````cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.tag == "Food")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            FindObjectOfType<SpawnManager>().SpawnFood();
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Is this a `DontDestroyOnLoad` object that you're using between different scenes?

Comment: @BenRubin I'm not sure what one of those is but everything here is happening in the same scene

Comment: Please update your code with your `Debug.Log` statements to show where your spawn limits have the correct value and where they have the incorrect value.

Comment: @BenRubin my code has been updated, the "Start Spawn limit" only gets logged once and the other "Spawn limits" are correct for the first spawn but then revert to `(0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Where do you call `SpawnFood()` from?  Could you also update your question to show the Inspector for the object that `SpawnManager` is attached to?

Comment: `SpawnFood()` is called from a player script when the player collides with an already existing food object and the question has been updated

Comment: Do you have some other code in your `SpawnManager` script?  I see that your Inspector lists the Spawn Delay property, which isn't in your example code.

Comment: Apologies I recently added that to try and test a different feature but that variable is currently not being used

Comment: So there are no other methods in `SpawnManager` other than the code that you've shown?

Comment: There is one but that is linked to the spawn delay variable which again is not being used

Comment: If you comment out the `Instantiate` in `SpawnFood`, does your second `Log` still show (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: The second one doesn't get triggered seeing as their is no object spawned meaning there will be no object for the player to collide with

Comment: Is your `food` property a prefab, or is it set to the scene object?

Comment: It should be a prefab that's what I set it to at least

Comment: Does the position show correctly in `Start` on the sequence and subsequent spawns?  Also, where do you destroy the food once the player picks it up?  Please show that code.

Comment: I mean "second", not "sequence"

Comment: The position shows correctly in start and then the first spawn, the rest result to 0, and the food is destroyed in the same script that calls the spawnfood method, I'll update my question

Comment: Do you have more than one objects in your scene called "Ground", or do you spawn additional objects and name them "Ground" (maybe as part of a prefab)?

Comment: I only have a single object named Ground and that does not change

Comment: It looks like you're calling `SpawnFood` on the object you just destroyed, right?  That might be OK since the object won't actually be destroyed until the next game loop, but it looks weird.  Try moving `FindObjectOfType<SpawnManager>().SpawnFood();` above the `Destroy`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190558/discussion-between-hcphoon-and-ben-rubin).